# Initialise 2D vector out of a structure c++

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

When I create a 2D vector out of a structure in the following way:

```
struct ScreenCoordinates{      //stores coordinates on screen
    GLdouble x;
    GLdouble y;
    GLdouble z;
};

vector<vector<ScreenCoordinates>> screenPoints_of_slices;
```

I get an error at this point:

```
screenPoints_of_slices[0][0].x = -1.0000;
```

[image: Vector Subsript out of range]

And cannot reach here:

```
screenPoints_of_slices[0][0].y = -1.0000;
screenPoints_of_slices[0][0].z = -1.0000;
```

Can someone explain me why is that?

Comment: What kind of error? Mind that right after `vector<vector<ScreenCoordinates>> screenPoints_of_slices;` declaration  the vector is empty (i.e., it has no storage allocated) thus,  doing `screenPoints_of_slices[0][0].x = -1.0000;` on an empty vector is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think that the error is pretty informative `vector subscript out of range`.

Comment: You cannot use `operator[]` when the size of the vector is `0`. Your code doesn't show that you have actually declared anything but an empty `std::vector` which _could_ contain other `std::vector` objects **but doesn't**.

Comment: You have practically done something to the effect of `std::vector<int> v; v[123] = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `vector<vector<ScreenCoordinates>> screenPoints_of_slices` have zero elements

You should do

```
vector<vector<ScreenCoordinates> > screenPoints_of_slices(1, vector<ScreenCoordinates>(1));
```

Basically the above step allocates the space for one element of vector of screenCoordinates with one element.

If you dont know the number of elements during the definition of `ScreenCoordinates` you should `push_back` the elements. A snippet for the same is shown below

```
vector<ScreenCoordinates> temp_vec;   //inner dim
ScreenCoordinates temp_cord = {0,0,0} // construct object

temp_vec.push_back(temp_cord);
temp_vec.push_back(temp_cord); // I am pushing same elem, but you can push any
temp_vec.push_back(temp_cord);

//Now push this back to the 2d vec
screenPoints_of_slices.push_back(temp_vec);
```

Once you are comfortable with the above code, take a look at `std::move` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

Comment: how would you push_back in 2D vector ?

Comment: first populate the inner dim by push_backs or initialization. Then push this back into the outer dim. I have updated the answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const size_t screenWidth  = 1280;
const size_t screenHeight = 720;
vector<vector<ScreenCoordinates>> screenPoints_of_slices(screenHeight,
                                                         vector<ScreenCoordinates>(screenWidth,
                                                                                   ScreenCoordinates{0, 0, 0}));
```

This will create a `screenHeight x screenWidth` matrix for you and initialize its elements with `{0, 0, 0}` (but you can omit that part  if you want).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously because you did not put anything in your vector. The vector is still empty, so you cannot reference any element inside it.